# What is BeanNameViewResolver?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I read the documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/BeanNameViewResolver.html), but I think that the Spring documentation is sometimes complex and hard to understand, so I need a little explanation about BeanNameViewResolver.

Can I get a code example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the documentation,BeanNameViewResolver resolves Views declared as beans. Most of the time you need it for some special-purpose views.

For example, we need to render an Excel spreadsheet. 
For the Excel generation you will Apache POI

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.6</version>
   </dependency>
```

So, you subclass AbstractExcelView and implement your custom logic to render a spreadsheet based on model values.

```
public class CustomExcelView extends AbstractExcelView { 

@Override
    protected void buildExcelDocument(Map model, HSSFWorkbook workbook,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
        Map<String,String> revenueData = (Map<String,String>) model.get("revenueData");
        //create a wordsheet
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Revenue Report");


    HSSFRow header = sheet.createRow(0);
    header.createCell(0).setCellValue("Month");
    header.createCell(1).setCellValue("Revenue");

    int rowNum = 1;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : revenueData.entrySet()) {
        //create the row data
        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(entry.getKey());
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(entry.getValue());
            }
}
```

}

and the controller simply adds the data

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;    
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/excelview")
public class ExcelController {

    public String getExcel(Model model){
        Map<String,String> revenueData = new HashMap<String,String>();
        revenueData.put("Jan-2010", "$100,000,000");
        revenueData.put("Feb-2010", "$110,000,000");
        revenueData.put("Mar-2010", "$130,000,000");
        revenueData.put("Apr-2010", "$140,000,000");
        revenueData.put("May-2010", "$200,000,000");
        model.addAttribute("revenueData",revenueData);

        return "myExcelView";
    }

}
```

Then declaring an BeanNameViewResolver makes it available to controllers: when controller returns String with view name myExcelView, your spreadsheet will be rendered.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />

    <bean id="myExcelView" class="com.example.CustomExcelView" />

</beans>
```

Comment: can I have full example for the problem?? I am new to spring.

Comment: yah but on ResourceBundle ViiewResolver and internalResource ViiewResolver

Comment: To your existing example where you used internalResourceViewResolver, now you will use BeanNameViewResolver

Comment: Kindly close the question by accepting the answer unless if the proposed solution doesn't work kindly let me know